# How to target an element when a modal opens using jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I open a modal I want the button to be disabled upon opening the modal.

But, this does not work:

```
$( '#addToCartNF' ).prop('disabled', true);
```

I know that if I wanted to click on it I would have to do something like:

```
$( 'body' ).on('click', '#addToCartNF', function() {
```

but I am not sure how to target the button inside the modal upon opening it.

```
 $( '.outlet' ).on('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var prodName = $(this).data('prodname');
           var prodId = $(this).data('id');

           $.ajax({
               url: url + '/CartAjax/ajaxModal',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {prodId: prodId},
               beforeSend: function() {
               $( '.outlet' ).prop('disabled', true);
               $( '.obtext' ).hide();
               $( '#outletspinner' ).show();

           },
           })
           .done(function (data) {
                 var modal = `

                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">${prodName} </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                <div>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="branches">
                                        <option value="">Select Outlet</option>
                                        ${data}
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default closeBranchModal">Close</button>
                                  <button class="btn btn-raised ripple-effect cart-btn closeBranchModal" id="addToCartNF" data-id="${prodId}"><div class="spinner" style="display: none;"></div><span class="cartBtnTextNF">ADD TO CART</span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    `;

                $(modal).modal(); 
                $( '#outletspinner' ).hide();
                $( '.obtext' ).show();
                $( '.outlet' ).prop('disabled', false);
           })

                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
            });
       })
```

Comment: Where's the modal html and button? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Okay, will post the code now. The modal is actually in a variable and opened by clicking on a button which uses this code: `$(modal).modal(); `

Comment: OK really the issue is more about the button I guess. Is it an `<a>` or `<button>` or `<input>` . Can't disable `<a>` but can add a disabled class

Comment: It is a <button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `on('click'..` the button is `this` inside the event handler

```
$( 'body' ).on('click', '#addToCartNF', function() {
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
     // or native element approach
     this.disabled = true;
})
```

Comment: This won't work because #addToCartNF is only available once the modal is open.

Comment: Yes it will because you are using event delegation

Comment: I just updated the main question to show the modal variable being set and shown after successful ajax request. By default the button should be disabled once the modal opens.

Comment: See [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: In your example code it is showing that I am clicking the add to cart button. That isn't the way I want it to work. When I click the button to open the modal, the add to cart button is inside the modal. That button inside the modal should be disabled.

Comment: The html you added doesn't include any ID `addToCartNF` and you never specified clearly how all this is supposed to work

Comment: Apologies, when the button is clicked to launch the modal, an ajax request is performed which gets data from the database. There is a dropdown and an add to cart button. By default nothing is selected and the add to cart button should be disabled. Only once something is selected should the button be enabled

Comment: I have edited the original question to include more code. I didn't post it all before because I didn't want to post too much code and bloat the question.

Comment: Fine but nor posting particulars has made this all quite confusing and answers don't fit what you were actually needing

Comment: I hear you, I am sorry for that.

Comment: So disable in ajax success. Use same `$('body').on()` delegation approach to add event listener to whatever it is inside modal you want to listen to to change it back. If you read the event delegation link above will see the modal element doesn't need to exist when you delegate the listener

Comment: That's the issue I am having, I don't know what to put in place of 'click' when using $( 'body')

Comment: So use `$('body').on('change',' dropdown selector...', function()...`

Comment: `$( 'body' ).on('change', 'select#branches', function() {
       $( '#addToCartNF' ).hide();
      })` I tried to hide the button as a test but nothing happens. The code does work if I just alert something though so the onchange bit is working

Comment: Does event occur...add an alert or console log inside handler function

Comment: Yes, alert works. `$( 'body' ).on('change', 'select#branches', function() {
      alert('something');
      })`

Comment: Not sure why hide() doesn't. No reason it shouldn't if that id is still the same and is not duplicated in page

Comment: Ah, I had the same ID somewhere else in the page!!

Comment: True. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

Change this

```
$( '#addToCartNF' ).prop('disabled', true);
```

with this one

```
$( '#addToCartNF' ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Using `prop()` is preferred way to change element properties and `disabled` is a valid property for some elements

Answer (score -2):

If you use bootstrap modal (which I will assume you do), please state this (and add appropriate tag)

You should use `show.bs.modal` event.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // you can check here what button originated the modal to show.
  $(this).find('#addToCartNF').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/)

### Update:

You can't disable an `a` tag, but you can unset the `href` attribute.
and then for visual appearance, you can add some classes to show the user that he cant click this.

For example:

```
  $(this).find('#addToCartNF').attr('href', '').addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Using `find()` for an ID is redundant since ID's are unique

Comment: Sure. But in case there ar multiple popups with the same HTML, this might not be the case.

Comment: How is that possible? An ID is only supposed to exist in page once otherwise need to use classes

Comment: Exactly. *An ID is only **supposed** to exist in page once*. To rely on the developer following standards is dangerous.